# Error code BIG QUERY: Expected end of input but got keyword SELECT bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Not sure why I'm getting this error code:

Expected end of input but got keyword SELECT bigquery

```
SELECT * FROM covid-deaths-323215.covid_deaths.covid_deaths 

SELECT Location, date, total_cases, total_deaths, (total_cases/population)*100 as DeathPercentage FROM covid-deaths-323215.covid_deaths.covid_deaths WHERE location = 'United States' order by 1,2
```

I'm able to run the query but yet the error appears on the side which doesn't allow me to save view.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What's your query?

Comment: SELECT*  FROM covid-deaths-323215.covid_deaths.covid_deaths

SELECT Location, date, total_cases, total_deaths, (total_cases/population)*100 as DeathPercentage
FROM covid-deaths-323215.covid_deaths.covid_deaths
WHERE location = 'United States'
order by 1,2

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14iTdJlBIdXPCHr4PbgsPOHmJqXcuhtnL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Paste it in the question!

Answer (score 0):

The query editor tries to interpret the entire contents of the editor window as valid SQL. You don't have a terminator on the first `SELECT` statement, so the parser keeps going and throws an error when it sees the second `SELECT` keyword because, taken all together, the contents of the editor don't represent a single valid SQL statement. If you select the statement and run it, the parser only looks at the text you've selected. I suspect that's why you can run the first statement but the editor still shows that error.

Try putting a semicolon at the end of the first statement, as in:
`SELECT * FROM covid-deaths-323215.covid_deaths.covid_deaths;`. Note you probably also need a space between `SELECT` and `*`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Would I have to do this for every SELECT I have for the Query's I've run?

Comment: It depends on what you want. For the scenario you're describing here, if you have multiple statements in a BigQuery console editor tab, you'll need to end every statement except the last statement in the tab with a semicolon to avoid the error you described.  See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#terminating_semicolons. Or you could open multiple tabs and put one query in each tab. But as you noted, if you're just selecting one query at a time and executing it, the error doesn't really matter.

Comment: "the error doesn't really matter" ... except for the fact that you can't save. I suppose that matters!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon ';' between two 'SELECT' statements.